# regex that filters out 'N' followed by any combination of digits

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need help on regex that  filters out  'N' followed  by any combination of digits.

```
import re
exp = "1+2+N32.23"
variable_refs = re.compile(r"([0-9]+)")
exp_template = re.sub(variable_refs, r'{key_\1}', exp)
```

Current output:
{key_1}+{key_2}+N{key_32}

Expected output:
{key_1}+{key_2}+N32.23

Comment: You may use: `re.sub(r'\b(?<!N)(\d+)', r'{key_\1}', exp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind `regex`:

```
import re

exp = "1+2+N32.12"
variable_refs = re.compile(r"\b(?<!N|\.)([0-9]+)")
exp_template = re.sub(variable_refs, r'{key_\1}', exp)

print(exp_template)
# {key_1}+{key_2}+N32.12
```

Comment: suppose I have exp = "1+2+N30".  it should return '{key_1}+{key_2}+N30' but currently it returns '{key_1}+{key_2}+N3{key_0}'

Comment: What if my exp is having decimals as well? eg.  "1+2+N32.12"

Comment: Do other numbers can also be decimals? Like `1.22+2.34+ N32.12`?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please edit your question and add details to it to help future readers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re
variable_refs = re.compile(r"\b(?<!N)([0-9])+")
exp_template = re.sub(variable_refs, r'{key_\1}', exp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a negative lookbehind `(?<!N)` or `(?<!\bN)` if `N` must be matched as a whole "word":

```
import re
exp = "1+2+N3"
variable_refs = re.compile(r"(?<!N)([0-9]+)")
exp_template = re.sub(variable_refs, r'{key_\1}', exp)
print(exp_template)
# => {key_1}+{key_2}+N3
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nEAR55)